# How to Bind Alt+Scroll for Zooming (Screen Magnifier) in Awesome Window Manager

Tags: awesome, xbindkeys, zoom

In Awesome Window Manager, how can I bind alt+Scroll for zooming?

For example, in KDE Plasma, it is done this way:

```
1) sudo apt install xbindkeys
2) Save the text below into ~/.xbindkeysrc  :
"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin invokeShortcut view_zoom_in"
    alt + b:4
"qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/kwin invokeShortcut view_zoom_out"
    alt + b:5

3) run: xbindkeys (it will automatically run each reboot, but this will run it now)
```

Ideally, I'd love to discover an X level solution for this feature. This way I can bind zooming to the mouse scroll wheel in a manner that works in any window manager or desktop environment that is X based.

Comment: what do you want to zoom in awesome? I think you might be confusing application level settings with window manager settings.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I want to zoom any where I point my mouse and alt-scroll, even if it is between two windows. This isn't a new idea, this is something that I've used for several years in various Desktop Environments. It is an accessibility feature, but it is also great for emphasizing things in presentations and screencasts.

Comment: hm, point is: I use awesome. Awesome has *nothing* to do with whether my firefox, my PDF viewer, my libreoffice, my inkscape zoom on alt-scroll. That's just their UI.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I wish you could conveniently experience the type of zooming that I show how to set up in KDE Plasma within my question. It is NOT an application level zoom. The type of zoom I'm talking is more global and undetected by applicaitons. Imagine taking a screenshot  of your desktop at a time you have numerous applications open. Then imagine opening that screenshot in an image viewer that allows you to zoom into any pixel of that image. Imagine being able to interact all applications that you zoom into. DEs provide this, and I'm trying to find a way to do it despite Awesome.

Comment: aaaaaah OK, sorry, now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome doesn't have an awesome zoom tool like the "Enhanced Zoom Desktop" provided in the Unity Desktop via compizconfig-settings-manager or the KDE zoom discussed in the question.

Instead, the best I could find was kmag:

```
sudo apt install kmag
```

This works pretty good in my multiple monitor setup. I can use one of my screens to magnify the other screen, which helps when I encounter applications that don't support 4K monitors.